# Inheritance of Type Members C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, member, type-members

I'm trying to use a type member of a class in its child, but I'm failing. In particular, I can't understand why this code does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        using t = T;
        
        A() {}
};

template <typename T>
class B: public A<T> {
    public:
        B() : A<T>() {}
        
        A<T>::t foo(A<T>::t x) {
            return x;
        }
};
```

I've also tried `A::t` and `B::t` but none of them is working. Maybe I'm missing something on how to access inherited type members. Compiler Error:

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘A<T>::t’ because ‘A<T>’ is a dependent scope
   A<T>::t foo(A<T>::t x) {
```

PS: I know that I could use simply `T` instead of trying to access `A::t` in this particular case, but the question is still valid.

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: fun fact: gccs error message tells you exactly how to fix it https://godbolt.org/z/Wh4r513bn. iirc there is a proposal to lift the requirement for `typename` when there is no ambiguity, until then we still have to put it just because the standard says so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `A<T>::t` depends on a template parameter, it requires a `typename`:

```
typename A<T>::t foo(typename A<T>::t x)
```

Because it depends on a template parameter, it must always be qualified (i.e. have `::` to the left of it), so just the plain `t` wouldn't work.

`typename B::t` would also work.

`typename A::t` wouldn't work because [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) `A` itself (i.e. the shorthand version that doesn't require template arguments) also depends on a template parameter. You could do `typename B::A::t`, but it's superfluous.

---

If you put this in your class: `using typename A<T>::t;`

Then you'll be able to use `t` as is. Notably, `using typename B::t;` doesn't work.

---

If the base class didn't depend on a template parameter (e.g. `template <typename T> class B : public A<int>`), then `typename` wouldn't be necessary.

In that case, all of the following would work: `t`, `B::t`, `A::t`, `B::A::t`, optionally with the template arguments for `A` and/or `B` specified.

Comment: What is the difference between the 2 possibilities? Why does the B version require the typename even no template needs to be specified?

Comment: @L.A. There is no difference. `B` acts a shorthand for `B<T>`, so it too depends on a template parameter.

Comment: Related: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/)